# LocalStack multi-tenant issue

Tags: localstack

Trying to follow this example as I'm wanting to create a multi-accounts in LocalStack, but running into some errors.  Wonder if anyone else had this problem.

Example followed: https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/multi-account-setups/

Error logs received:

```
make_bucket failed: s3://bucket-account-one An error occurred (500) when calling the CreateBucket operation (reached max retries: 2): Internal Server Error
```

```
2022-05-21T02:17:53.888:INFO:localstack_ext.bootstrap.licensing: Successfully activated API key
Waiting for all LocalStack services to be ready

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/server/http2_server.py", line 185, in index
result = await run_sync(handler, request, data)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/asyncio.py", line 85, in run_sync
return await loop.run_in_executor(thread_pool, copy_context().run, func_wrapped)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/threads.py", line 38, in run
result = self.func(self.params, **kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/asyncio.py", line 30, in _run
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 972, in handler
return modify_and_forward(
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 516, in wrapper
value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/generic_proxy.py", line 596, in modify_and_forward
listener_result = listener.forward_request(
File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/localstack_ext/services/edge.py.enc", line 202, in forward_request
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/edge.py", line 171, in forward_request
self._require_service(api)
File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/edge.py", line 228, in _require_service
raise HTTPErrorResponse("failed to get service for %s: %s" % (api, e), code=500)
localstack.utils.server.http2_server.HTTPErrorResponse: failed to get service for s3:
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the docs on a recent version of LocalStack

```sh
$ localstack --version
0.14.2.1
```

While testing it, I did not encounter any error (except that it needs an `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as well). Can you please upgrade your LocalStack version (if you are using an old one) and validate it once again?